# Count the number of instances in a Google Sheets array where a formatted input meets a specified logical condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, heatmap, array-formulas, countif

I want to create a heatmap in Google Sheets that displays the most active hours for team members using conditional formatting. The first page has columns for each weekday and rows for each team member, with cells containing their start and end times.
The second page has columns for each weekday and rows for each hour in a 24-hour cycle. I'm having trouble getting the number of people available at a given hour from the data on the first page. And it's hard for me to find the problem's source, since Sheets don't offer good solutions for debugging or doesn't give me an error.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M-WZLJdo0vWPyksKK0keqhSS4VflQKq05IBJO2-dy_8/edit?usp=sharing)'s a link to an example of what i want the output to look like.

I've tried 3 different solutions. Using `=ARRAYFORMULA`, `=COUNTIF` and `=COUNTIFS`

The logical comparisons work nicely, it's when I try to count them where I run into a problem.

Here's what I tried to do with arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    SUM(    
        VALUE(
            IF(
                OR(
                    ISBLANK(Page1!$B$2:$B$4),
                    ISBLANK(Page1!$C$2:$C$4)
                ),
                0,
                IF(
                    OR(
                        MOD($A2,1)>=TIME(LEFT(Page1!$B$2:$B$4,FIND(":",Page1!$B$2:$B$4)-1),0,0),
                        MOD($A2,1)<TIME(LEFT(Page1!$C$2:$C$4,FIND(":",Page1!$C$2:$C$4)-1),0,0)
                    ),
                    1,
                    0
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And here's what I tried to do with countif:

```
=COUNTIF(
    IF
    (
        AND
        (
            TIMEVALUE(Page2!$A2) >= TIME(LEFT(Page1!$B$2:$B$4,FIND(":",Page1!$B$2:$B$4)-1),0,0),
            TIMEVALUE(Page2!$A2) <= TIME(LEFT(Page1!$C$2:$C$4,FIND(":",Page1!$C$2:$C$4)-1),0,0)
        ),
        "TRUE",
        "FALSE"
    ),
    "TRUE"
)
```

One suggestion was to use `=COUNTIFS(Page1!B2:B4, "<="&A2, Page1!C2:C4, ">="&A2)` but this also always returns 0.

Comment: @player0 added document with desired output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A), TEXT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(7, 1)&"×"&
 SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(BYCOL(Page1!B2:O4, LAMBDA(y, (BYROW(y, LAMBDA(x, 
 TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, HOUR(OFFSET(x,,1)-x), 0)/24+x))))))),,9^9)), 
 "skipping 2", ), " ")), "×"), "select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1", ), 
 {"h:mm", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"}), SEQUENCE(1, 7)+1, 0))+0)
```

[image]

---

input:

[image]